# Output from xUnit tests run with Visual Studio test runner not shown in Output window

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, xunit.net

I created a fresh .NET Core Class Library project named `FooBarBaz`. I've then used the package manager console to run:

- `Install-Package xunit xunit`
- `Install-Package xunit xunit.runners.visualstudio`

This is the only code I have added:

```
using Xunit;
using Xunit.Abstractions;

namespace FooBarBaz
{
    public class Class1
    {
        private readonly ITestOutputHelper output;

        public Class1(ITestOutputHelper output)
        {
            this.output = output;
            output.WriteLine("OUTPUT FROM MY CONSTRUCTOR");
        }

        [Fact]
        public void SmokeTest()
        {
            output.WriteLine("OUTPUT FROM MY TEST");
            Assert.True(true);
        }
    }
}
```

This is based straight on [the xUnit.net documentation example](https://xunit.github.io/docs/capturing-output). I know that the documentation goes on to talk about "Message Sinks" and whatnot, but I could've sworn I saw the message **in the *Output* window** of visual studio. In my real project this seems to work only erratically.

I know I can click the "Output" hyperlink after selecting a test and see it, but that's just one step extra, and that output doesn't have a monospace font either (which I'd like to have).

See this:

[image: Output window without output]

How do I configure xUnit to provide output *in the Output window*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After typing the question and fiddling around some more, the completely obscure solution popped up: **only tests that *fail*** show `ITestOutputHelper` output in the Output window.

Try changing the assertion to `Assert.True(false);` and you'll get this:

[image: Output window with output]

Not sure why that's the default, or how you'd change it.

Comment: you can do trace/debug.writeline to put stuff in the output all the time if you wish. The reason it's not wired through by default is that the idea is that due to test parallelism the output would not always be helpful (and is a perf drag)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The parallel part makes only partly sense to me though: if 58 out of 1001 tests fail during parallel runs, the output would be jumbled too, non?

Comment: (The perf thing makes total sense though.)

Comment: no, the `ITestOutputAdapter` is passed to Test Class per run so the captured output is just for that run - its the VS shell that decides to not to expose it unless it failed though (which saves memory etc in addition to screen real estate)

Answer (score 2):

What Jeroen wrote regarding `ITestOutputHelper` is correct, so you can't use it for "live" messages. But I have a workaround for you:

If you're debugging anyway and activated "Debug" mode, nothing stops you from doing something like

> `loopCount++;` 
> `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Processing Entries ({loopCount} of {loopMax}) ...");`

This will show up in the "Debug" window (i.e. in the Output window there is a dropdown where you need to select "Show output from Debug"). It appears immediately, ideal for long running loops etc.

Don't worry, those messages show up only in "Debug" configuration. To disable them, select "Release", and they won't appear any more - so it is easy to turn them on or off.

You can also write a helper function like:

```
private void Print(string msg, string test = "") 
{ 
    Debug.WriteLine($"{nameof(NameOfTestClass)}{test}: {msg}"); 
    output?.WriteLine(msg); 
}
```

Which will write into debug console in real time, but at the same time write into the test runner's output space.

You can use it in your Facts and Theories like

```
Print("Something happened");
```

or

```
Print("Something happened", "-Test1");
```

And a complete test class would look like:

```
using LiveOut = System.Diagnostics.Debug;
// using LiveOut = System.Console;
public class Test_Class
{

    ITestOutputHelper Output;
    public Test_Class(ITestOutputHelper _output)
    {
        Output = _output;
    }

    private void Print(string msg, string test = "") 
    {
        LiveOut.WriteLine($"{nameof(Test_Class)}{test}: {msg}");
        Output?.WriteLine(msg);
    }

    [Fact]
    void Test_Xunit()
    {
        void _print(string msg) => Print(msg, $"-{nameof(Test_Xunit)}");

        for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
        {
            _print(i.ToString());
            Assert.True(i > 0);
            Thread.Sleep(20);
        }
    }

}
```

In this case, you can choose between two using commands:

```
using LiveOut = System.Diagnostics.Debug;
```

or

```
using LiveOut = System.Console;
```

Depending on your needs you will have the output either on the debug window or on the console window.

Comment: Beware that you need to debug your test so that Debug.WriteLine will write to the debug output. If you run your tests, it won't print anything

Comment: @ihebiheb - Yes, to use Debug.Writeline, you have to be in the Debug configuration. But you can use `#if DEBUG using LiveOut = System.Diagnostics.Debug; #else  using LiveOut = System.Console; #endif` to get around this issue.