# Resharper: How to write to console output

Tags: resharper, xunit.net

I'm using **Resharper 2019 1.3.** 
I'm runnning unit test using **Xunit**.
Inside my testmethod decorated with **[Fact]** I want to write to Resharper output using Console.WriteLine. 
For some reason it is not working.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
public class NumberTest
{
    public NumberTest()
    {
    }

    [Fact]
    public void NewNumber_should_randomize()
    {
        var number1 = Number.NewNumber();

        Console.WriteLine(number1.Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newer versions of xUnit have decoupled logging slightly. Have a look at [the "Capturing Output" docs](https://xunit.net/docs/capturing-output), telling you to do something like this:

```
public class NumberTest
{
    private readonly ITestOutputHelper output;

    public NumberTest(ITestOutputHelper output)
    {
        this.output = output;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void NewNumber_should_randomize()
    {
        var number1 = Number.NewNumber();

        output.WriteLine(number1.Value);

        throw new Exception("Output _might_ only show if the test fails, depending on the runner");
    }
}
```

However, **take care**, I noticed before in a similar Q&A that [the Visual Studio runner might only show output if a test *fails*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53795414/419956).

Comment: I just tested with VS 2019, the result is showed even if the test succeeds (as well as in the link you referenced https://xunit.net/docs/capturing-output). To get it, the test tree have to be expand to the last child (`Fact` method).